# JavaFX SceneBuilder 2.0 doesn't open FXML for custom components with fx:root as main layout tag

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have custom component with layout on FXML file which containts line

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" spacing="10.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
```

I create this file on SceneBuilder 1.0, but then i try open this file on SceneBuilder 2.0 i got Exception

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root hasn't been set. Use method setRoot() before load.
/Users/dmitrynelepov/Development/SogazGit/smpb/SMProjectBrownRelease/SMPBProxy/engine/fxml/component_daemon_viewer.fxml:14
```

Also must to tell: in applications this fxml loadings fine with setting root by code.

In official tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm) tells:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <TextField fx:id="textField"/>
    <Button text="Click Me" onAction="#doSomething"/>
</fx:root>
```

[image]

As u can see Oracle tells:**Delete the AnchorPane markup that NetBeans IDE automatically generated.**

But it's not working.

**UPDATE**

SceneBuilder 2.0 Build 7 - the problem persists

JDK8 b117 - the problem persists

Link JIRA: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/DTL-5968

Comment: when i used a fxml which developer scene builder 1.1 with 2.0 its work perfect fine...what you tring to achieve ??

Comment: just try fx:root example from my question

Comment: by default scene builder provide anchor pane and its better that if working with in anchor pane...its more reliable for working

Comment: Ashul, i just try do tutorial example works.

Comment: i working on applications and always we used with anchor pane...i think its better approch..scene bulider 2.0 have a properties with javafx 8 ...may be these reason have some changes here

Comment: Anshul, i just try do what tells me tutorial from oracle, read section: Create the Basic User Interface->Add code for the root container as shown in Example 5-1.

Comment: yep i read it..sorry i am not found why its not working... may be this help you

Comment: I already report to Oracle about it:https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/DTL-5968

Comment: @AnshulParashar Your recent spate of adding tags to posts, while moderately helpful, is really too minor a change to add real value.  Look for places to add value to posts.

Comment: @paqogomez i feel some tag missing dats y i am doing this...i'll do better in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for SceneBuilder developers.

Bug with https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/DTL-5968 has fixed.

And on SceneBuilder 2.0 build 9 - problem was solved.

Question closed.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite fixed for me.  I am still getting this error.

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root hasn't been set. Use method setRoot() before load. 
/C:/path-to-my-fxml/foo.fxml:11

at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:86)
at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:74)
```

With the latest version of Scenebuilder 2.0 dev release:

```
Build Information Version: 2.0-b09, Changeset: 12f988d79fe6 Date:
2013-12-19 09:33
```

Not sure what the workaround is at this point other than to keep on switching the fx:root for a concrete container object.  Bummer.

- chooks

Comment: Appears fixed in Version: 2.0-b10, Changeset: 48fc80a12d33